# UIPickerView Datasource & Delegate: ERROR

Tags: swift, delegates, swift2, datasource, uipickerviewcontroller

I'm not sure why this happen?.

Because in other projects, with the same lines, it worked perfectly.

---

[image]

---

Comment: Have you implemented the delegate and datasource methods?

Answer (score 1):

Check your `@IBOutLet` it's named `market`

Just change the name with

```
self.market.datasource = self
self.market.delegate = self
```

Check the declaration name of `UIPickerView`.